# Uses of everyday in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is it the same to say "he wears a suit to work everyday" and "he wears a suit everyday to work"?or is there a rule for that?

Answer (score 1):

These are both wrong.

"everyday" is an adjective. You could talk about "an everyday suit" if for example you were comparing it to a special one only worn to church on Sundays.

However if you're asking about "every day", then either of these is correct:

> He wears a suit to work every day.
> He wears a suit every day to work.

Comment: I just don't get why people don't upvote this. For pete's sake. :)